# How to post an array with HTTParty

Tags: ruby, httparty

I need to POST an array with [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty).

My array is `[1, 2, 3]` and the API expects to receive the body to be in the form

```
"story_hash=1&story_hash=2&story_hash=3"
```

It's not really important but [here's the docs for the API in question](http://www.newsblur.com/api#/reader/mark_story_hashes_as_read).

The solution I have at the moment is:

```
params = [1, 2, 3].inject('') { |memo, h| memo += "&story_hash=#{h}" }
# Strip the first '&'
params.slice!(0)

options = { body: params }
HTTParty.post('/reader/mark_story_hashes_as_read', options)
```

Is there a better way (the ideal solution would be a feature of HTTParty that I just don't know of)?

---

I tried the following method:

```
options = {
  body: { story_hash: [1, 2, 3] }
}
HTTParty.post('/reader/mark_story_hashes_as_read', options)
```

But that seems to erroneously send a body like this:

```
"story_hash[]=1&story_hash[]=2&story_hash[]=3"
```

Comment: That body isn't erroneous really, it's just not quite what you're expecting. That would be reconstructed (by Rails, for example) as an array parameter called story_hash containing three elements. (Take a look at how the results of a multiselect in a form are posted to rails--same idea).

Comment: @struthersneil Yeah sorry, I probably shouldn't have used that word. I just meant "unsuitable for my purposes".

Comment: I know--I just added the comment for passing googlers in case someone's wondering why their arrays are encoded oddly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[1, 2, 3].map{|h| "story_hash=#{h}"}.join("&")
#=> "story_hash=1&story_hash=2&story_hash=3"
```

I would also recommend using `CGI.escape(h.to_s)` instead of `h`, it would encode the values for url (unless `HTTParty` already does that for you). So escaped version looks like:

```
[1, 2, 3].map{|h| "story_hash=#{CGI.escape(h.to_s)}"}.join("&")
#=> "story_hash=1&story_hash=2&story_hash=3"
```

Comment: This answer could use some clarification. Where exactly should that be called?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @tihom, just want to add that if you are going to use it more than once it would be good to override the query_string_normalizer method.

```
class ServiceWrapper
  include HTTParty

  query_string_normalizer proc { |query|
    query.map do |key, value|
      value.map {|v| "#{key}=#{v}"}
    end.join('&')
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTTParty::HashConversions.to_params](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/HashConversions.to_params) method for this purpose

```
require "httparty"
HTTParty::HashConversions.to_params((1..3).map { |x| ["story_hash", x] })
# => story_hash=1&story_hash=2&story_hash=3
```

Comment: This does not work: `NoMethodError: undefined method `to_hash' for [["story_hash", 1], ["story_hash", 2], ["story_hash", 3]]:Array`. I tried this using Ruby 2.2